# OpenGL Video Rendering - How do I make the texels semi-transparent?

Tags: android, video, opengl-es

This is my current `onDrawFrame()` code for the `GLVideoRenderer` I use to render a video:

```
private void drawActual(boolean useFilter) {
    Log.i("current_pos", currentFilterPosition+" "+Constant.ILLUSION);
    /*
    if(currentFilterPosition != Constant.ILLUSION) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        GLES20.glClear( GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    } else {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GLES20.glClear( GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
    */

    if(currentFilterPosition != storedFilterPosition)
    {
        /*Changing fragment shader and resetting the uniform locations*/

        storedFilterPosition = currentFilterPosition;
    }
    Log.e("use_filter", "true");
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
    checkGlError("glUseProgram");

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID);
    checkGlError("glBindTexture");

    Log.i("current_float_timestamp", muTimestampFloatHandle+"");
    onPreDrawFrame();
    checkGlError("onPreDrawFrame");

    mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maPosition");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maPositionHandle");

    mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maTextureHandle");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maTextureHandle");

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    checkGlError("glmuMVPMatrixHandleSetting");
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, mSTMatrix, 0);
    checkGlError("glmuSTMatrixHandleSetting");

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    checkGlError("glDrawArrays");
    //GLES20.glFinish();
}
```

And this is the fragment shader I use to try rendering the video frames semi-transparently:

```
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
precision mediump float;

uniform samplerExternalOES u_Texture;

varying highp vec2 v_TexCoordinate;

uniform float uParamValue1; //filter strength

void main()
{
    vec4 texel = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate).rgba;
    texel.a *= 0.2;
    /*
    if(texel.a > 0.5)
        discard;
        */
    gl_FragColor += texel;
}
```

My problem is that the alpha values in my video frames must be all 255 or 1.0 because when doing the depth testing with that commented-out code in the fragment shader, it's either all there, or all gone. What's worse, when I use this code, the alpha reduction doesn't have an effect - the renderer just renders the RGB components only.

My expectation for that fragment shader is actually to apply a bit of that motion blur effect, so I want the shader to render the video frame semi-transparently, removing the clear functions to prevent the renderer from clearing the frame before.

How do I do this, and is my code missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal correctly you are missing blending. Look into `glBlendFunc` or in your case more likely `glBlendFuncSeparate`. Also do not forget to enable blending using `glEnable`. In your case you also might find useful to mask out alpha using `glColorMask`.

So to look at a usual drawing pipeline you will start with come background color using `glClear` or with some scene already being drawn. Now you wish to draw some objects over that effectively blending it.

The most common function when blending is using `glBlendFunc(src_alpha, one_minus_src_alpha)`. Which means it will take whatever is on the buffer now and mix it with the oncoming color using only the oncoming alpha. So assume the buffer has been cleared to `(0,0,0,0)` and you are drawing `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5)` which is a semitransparent white color. The result is:

```
(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5)*0.5 + (0,0,0,0)*(1.0-0.5) = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.25)
```

As you can see the color is all good being at `0.5` but alpha is at awesome `0.25` which will be an issue when exporting to some image or something but is not an issue when looking at it on opaque surface (which is mostly the case) because alpha is simply ignored there.

So in comparison if we clear to opaque black color we get

```
res = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5)*0.5 + (0,0,0,1)*(1.0-0.5) = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75)
```

which really doesn't make a better result.

A solution is obviously in using `glBlendFuncSeparate` which uses separate parameters for alpha component only and can be used as `glBlendFuncSeparate(src_alpha, one_minus_src_alpha, gl_zero, gl_one)`. This will do exactly the same on the color but the alpha component will be intact, staying at whatever it started with.

But since you don't want to work with alpha on target buffer you can just mask it out and work on RGB components using `glColorMask(true, true, true, false)`. This will not disable alpha at any point, it will only disable writing to it.

So assume something like this should work:

```
glClearColor(0,0,0,1); // Set clear color to opaque black
glClear(); // Clear the buffer

glDisable(blend); // Disable blending to draw background
glColorMask(true, true, true, false); // Disable writing to alpha component

glDraw(originalVideoFrame); // Draw the background

glEnable(blend); // Enable blending
glBlendFunc(src_alpha, one_minus_src_alpha); // Set standard blending function
glColorMask(true, true, true, false); // Redundant call, may be removed

glDraw(semitransparentFrame); // Draw semitransparent part
```

To check this with a single pixel let us say the first part will be drawing a red color that is a bit transparent `(1, 0, 0, 0.75)` and then blending with a yellow semitransparent pixel `(1, 1, 0, 0.5)` this will happen:

1. `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` From clear
2. `(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` Draw red color. Both alpha and blending is disabled so only colors are copied ignoring everything else
3. `(1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0)` Drawing yellow color using blending as `(1, 1, 0, 0.5)*0.5 + (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)*(1.0-0,5) = (0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.25) + (0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5) = (1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.75)` ignoring changes on alpha again.

I hope this helps you understand blending and solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the `GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND)` solution. That's part of the answer I seek. The other part is actually about keeping the buffer of the previous frame instead of clearing it every frame. Is the solution for that involving `Framebuffer`s?

Comment: @Gensoukyou1337 If I understand correctly you will then need 2 buffers which is pretty standard. In your case that would be using a FBO, frame buffer object with attached texture. Basically this means you will be drawing to texture and then use that texture for post-processing. It is probably best if you look into some examples of it...